# Instantiate a eloquent Model that alrready exists in the database with attributes?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

Currently I have the attributes in array but that model is already exists in the table how do I instantiate the Model without querying again, so that I can use the functions. I know there is way. Please point me into the right direction. following is the structure of the arrays of some values of the model I have currently.

```
"url" => null
  "is_default" => 1
  "is_verified" => 2
  "verification_token" => null
```

Comment: Simply create an instance such as `$model = new YourModel(['url' => '']);`

Comment: but this will create a new instance, that means when we call save it will insert new row

Comment: So don't call save then and problem solved.

Comment: Does your code know the "id" of the existing record on the database?

Comment: the data exists I just need the model instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it, 
We can instantiate the model by values

```
$model = new YourModel(['name' => 'foo', 'other_attribute'=>3], false);
```

We can pass a second parameter as false which will say that it exists in database

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `firstOrNew` and `firstOrCreate` method. ([Laravel 5.2 reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-inserts) )

Both methods will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. But, `firstOrNew` will not insert the data into database and you will need to call `save()` method manually.

> The firstOrNew method, like firstOrCreate will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a new model instance will be returned. Note that the model returned by firstOrNew has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it:

Comment: but i dont want to query just instantiate the model